# how to run bash script from Docker Image

Tags: bash, docker

I have created a docker image from a Dockerfile. Projects working perfectly. I've a few tests and to invoke those tests I've created a **run_tests.sh** file, I've made the file executable too.

So, when I run `docker run -it --rm <image_name> run_tests.sh` it should output the test result, instead it outputting server ip address it listening to.

How to run bash script from a Docker Image without entering it's shell?

This is my Dockerfile...

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gnupg -y

# copy project
COPY . /app/

# making executable test file and entrypoint file for bash shell
RUN chmod +x run_tests.sh 
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your Dockerfile to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of things to check:

**Use `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile.**  The command after the `docker run` image name overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`, and if both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` are present then the `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  You can work around this using `docker run --entrypoint` as described in [@MarcosParreiras's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71923544) but there's no benefit to using `ENTRYPOINT` here; just use `CMD` instead.

```sh
CMD ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Make sure your script can execute normally.**  It should be executable (as in `chmod +x`), and it should begin with a "shebang" line

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# ^^^ as the very very first thing in the script
```

Outside Docker you should be able to run `./run_tests.sh` and it should run without explicitly naming an interpreter.  If the file is executable on the host (and checked into source control as executable) then Dockerfile `COPY` will preserve the executable bit and you don't need to `RUN chmod` in the Dockerfile.

(You can do the same thing with your `entrypoint.sh` script and omit the explicit `sh` interpreter from the `CMD`.)

**Put the script in `$PATH` somewhere.**  `/usr/local/bin` is often a good choice.

(In a Python context, if your `setup.cfg` file contains [setuptools entry points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html), then `pip install` will put its wrapper scripts into `/usr/local/bin` and you can just run them; this is done automatically.)

Putting these all together, you'd get a Dockerfile like:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh run_tests.sh /usr/local/bin
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/*
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

And you should be able to run exactly the `docker run` command you initially proposed

```sh
docker run -it --rm image_name run_tests.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for describing it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can run achieve that by running:

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint '' <image_name> /bin/bash -c './run_tests.sh'
```

or

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint '' <image_name> sh -c './run_tests.sh'
```

in case your image has only `sh` available

In either case, you are just running a container from the desired image and then running either `/bin/bash` or `sh` with the `-c` flag, that allows you to define the command to run from a string. Also, by setting `--entrypoint ''`, you are overriding the default entrypoint set on the Dockerfile. When you have an entrypoint set, the docker command would be appended as parameters for that, so we override the entrypoint to be an empty one.

Also, you should no use the options `-it` in this case, given that they are used when you want to interact with the container (i.e access the terminal within the container).

Comment: still outputting the same server ip address as before

Comment: Hm, ok. What is the content of the `entrypoint.sh` file? As this file is called in the ENTRYPOINT, what you run as COMMAND will be then be passed as parameters to this script. That probably is causing the issue. A way to workaround that would be overriding the docker entrypoint with: `docker run --rm  --entrypoint '' <image_name> sh -c './run_tests.sh'`

Comment: Thank you, man! it works, totally on point.